# Gedit .LOG feature

Tags: gedit, text-editor

In MS Notepad I can create a file like this:

```
.LOG

I updated function xyz(), line 32 today.
```

save it, and when I open it:

```
.LOG

I updated function xyz(), line 32 today.

25-10-14 8:04:56
```

How can I achive the same functionality in `gedit`, or a similar program for Ubuntu?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the functionality of adding the date as a last line is done by notepad itself? Never head of such a function...

Comment: Certain, my computer science teacher showed me it yesterday! http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/260563?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: @Jan it's a old trick. Only Notepad does it (at least without plugins, etc.), I think.

Comment: Interesting feature, never heard of it before.

Comment: Very useful for keeping track of code changes!

Comment: It has been around since the Windows 3.1 days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure of the exact behaviour of Notepad here. While I don't know how to make `vim` do that based on some existing text in a file, I could make `vim` do something similar for files of a certain extension, by adding this to `~/.vimrc`:

```
au BufWritePre *.log :normal G"=strftime("\n%b %d, %Y %X\n")^Mp
```

Explanation:

- `au` - stands for `AutoCommand`, the `vim` way of executing some action for some event.
- `BufWritePre` - the `vim` event for just before writing out a file.
- `*.log` - the files to do this for (you could pick another extension)
- `:normal`  - Go to normal mode (the mode you're usually in when you start `vim`)
- `G` - go to the last line
- `"=strftime("\n%b %d, %Y %X\n")^M` - Into the default buffer (`"`), copy the output of the `strftime` function (the `^M` is a literal newline, obtained by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd>, then <kbd>Enter</kbd>)
- `p` - then paste the buffer.

Each time I write the file using `:w`, the current date will be appended to the file:

```
$ vim test.log
$ vim test.log
$ cat test.log 
I did some work.

Oct 26, 2014 01:15:55  IST

Didn't I?

Oct 26, 2014 01:16:02  IST
```

This is quite customizable. You can pick your file extension, leave out the `G` if you want to append the date after the current line, modify the time format, use other events (see `:h autocmd-events`).

Comment: Where do you put the command?

Comment: @Tim forgot the most important instruction. :( In your `~/.vimrc`.

Comment: I have one called `.vimrc-local`, do I need to create `.vimrc`?

Comment: @Tim that is surprising. If you don't have a `~/.vimrc`, I think you should create one, and (at the least) add `set nocompatible` at the top.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the ".LOG" functionality of Notepad for several years and have grown to depend on it quite a bit. My answer to you is not as sophisticated as some of the replies here (I suspect that is because I am not as savvy as some of the people who have attempted to help you herein...) When the Microsoft XP OS was abandoned by Microsoft I chose to make a leap-of-faith by porting my old XP machine to Debian Linux. (Couldn't love a human baby as much as I love Debian Linux BTW... ;o)! ) In any case, having the same dilemma as yourself I simply installed WINE and used Notepad from within it. I hope this helps you.